# Closing connection to browser early and returning respond status

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, connection, httpmodule

I am implementing a custom IHttpModule in a project, which filter file uploading and provide upload status.
I want the custom module to close the connection early (don't want to receive all the data the other side send, which is allowed to be big, save the incoming bandwidth).

Is it a possibility using HTTP protocol?

I tried sending "ContentLength: 0" and "Connection: close" header, flush the response, close the connection (HttpWorkerRequest.CloseConnection).

```
workerRequest.SendStatus(400, "Bad request");
workerRequest.SendKnownResponseHeader(HttpWorkerRequest.HeaderContentLength, "0");
workerRequest.SendKnownResponseHeader(HttpWorkerRequest.HeaderConnection, "close");
workerRequest.FlushResponse(false);
workerRequest.CloseConnection();
((HttpApplication)sender).CompleteRequest();
```

The browser/firefox response is displaying the "Connection reset" error message.
Without any sign of receiving any data/header/status from the server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An http client expects response only after it has completed sending the data. You should modify the client to make multiple requests of small sizes so a response can be sent to it instead of having server close the connection (which will not work and isn't working as you've tested already).

Check the http handler implemented in [http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/](http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/69724#1495559) for a sample of how it is typically done.

Comment: modifying the client is out of the question, as it must be a browser

Comment: Well in that case the browsers don't read status either. There is no point in sending status.

Comment: For upload progress; you always have to write your own client side plugin in flash or silverlight

Comment: Thanks, look like the closing connection is not plausible. I will disagree with you about the "always needing the plugin for upload progress". I've seen implementations in pure javascript form.

Comment: Pur js implementations are only possible in html5 I think but thats not standardized yet.

Comment: What we're implementing right now is based purely on ajax js, so not really using any new html5 feature. It uses a form targeting an invisible iframe, so the main page won't reload, and then open another ajax to the server for requesting upload progress. It's not done yet. Check NeatUpload out. They are open source and uses JS (but can also support fallback to Flash).